# #ifdef [true condition] #endif block. Commenting out #ifdef & #endif lines changes compile?

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

I have two header files.  One calls the other after #define-ing a symbol used in the other one with #ifdef [symbol]... lotsa code #endif.

In VS2017, the code between the #ifdef & #endif shows as 'active' (not greyed out), so it thinks [symbol] is true and includes the code in the active code set.

However, If I comment out the #ifdef [symbol] and #endif lines, the result of the compile changes drastically - how can this be?  I thought the #ifdef & #endif macros were pre-processor directives and don't exist at all for purposes of compiling the code.  If #ifdef [symbol] evaluates as true, I thought they just disappeared.  What am I missing?

First header file:

```
#ifndef _MPU6050_6AXIS_MOTIONAPPS20_H_
#define _MPU6050_6AXIS_MOTIONAPPS20_H_

#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "helper_3dmath.h"

// MotionApps 2.0 DMP implementation, built using the MPU-6050EVB evaluation board
#define MPU6050_INCLUDE_DMP_MOTIONAPPS20

#include "MPU6050.h"
```

In the second header file (MPU6050.H), there is a long class definition for 'Class MPU6050' and this definition has a block guarded by

```
#ifdef MPU6050_INCLUDE_DMP_MOTIONAPPS20
....
....
....
#endif
```

This (I believe) is the source of some 'one definition rule' violations I've been trying to track down, so as an experiment I commented out the #define & #endif lines, thinking now there would be only one possible definition for 'Class MPU6050' and life would be good.  What actually happened is the compiler blew a whole lot of 'undefined symbol' errors, as if the 'MPU6050_INCLUDE_DMP_MOTIONAPPS20' symbol hadn't been defined after all and the guard lines were *preventing* the guarded code from being compiled, even though VS2017's Intellisense shows it 'active'.

Since the symbol 'MPU6050_INCLUDE_DMP_MOTIONAPPS20' is defined, the guarded code in MPU6050.H should be compiled whether or not the #ifdef & #endif lines are actually there, right??

What am I missing?

The actual files are MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h and MPU6050.H from the Arduino\MP6050 folder at [Jeff Rowberg's i2cDev GitHub account](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050)

TIA,

Frank

02/06/19 Addition: As a test, I placed a 'known-bad' line in the #ifdef/#endif guarded block, and the compiler flagged the line as an error. I believe this proves that the guarded block is indeed 'active' from the point of view of the compiler.

In addition, I commented out the line in MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h that #defined the 'MPU6050_INCLUDE_DMP_MOTIONAPPS20' symbol.  Now the editor shows the guarded code as 'inactive' (grayed out), and the compiler acts consistently with that (complains that is is missing the function declarations from the guarded code section).

So, I have what appears to be a paradox; The compiler believes that the guarded code is active, but believes it disappears when I comment out the #ifdef & #endif lines, which should have been removed by the pre-processor ever saw the guarded code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual compilation command line, but I'd guess your editor is wrong.

Comment: Rather than deleting the ifdef block, try sticking #define .... at the top of your file.

Comment: I'd suggest invoking the preprocessor manually on your source file to see what it's doing.  On UNIX use `cpp`, for Visual Studio it's [cl.exe /P](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=vs-2017).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_MPU6050_6AXIS_MOTIONAPPS20_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.